# Any observed relevant difference would have to be interpreted - or "should be interpreted"?

Tags: conditional-constructions

From a guidance document that describes how the similarity of a newly-developed drug to an already existing drug should be assessed and confirmed:

> A biosimilar drug should be similar to the reference drug in physicochemical and biological terms. Any observed significant difference **would have to be interpreted**, since it could contradict the biosimilarity principle.

Can I use this "would have to be interpreted" here, or is it better to use "should be interpreted"?

> A biosimilar drug should be similar to the reference drug in physicochemical and biological terms. Any observed significant difference **should be interpreted**, since it could contradict the biosimilarity principle.

I think it is better with **should** because "would have to be" implies some condition that remains undersribed, some "if-phrase" or "if-clause". With "would have" we have "a second conditional" construction describing "an unreal situation".

Comment: I agree. "Should be" creates more urgency, which could be and is generally important in the medical world.

Comment: I prefer **would have to be** as this implies necessity. To me **should** is less forceful. *I should do some work today, but the sun is shining so I'll play golf instead.*

Comment: would have to be... would need to be....must be.....   I'm with djna on the necessity element here. But there is also a future task involved, and "would have to be" is better suited to expressing that than the simple modal **should** or **must**.

Comment: @TRomano - very interesting! I was so sure that **should be** is the better choice. I thought that "would have to be" implied non-reality, and that in a guidance document "should" was better. Live and learn.

Comment: Hmmm, who is your audience? And in what format? Are they hearing this or reading this? I'm also considering, "will have to be."

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang - as I wrote, this is a guidance document. The audience is (are?) pharmaceutical specialists in companies that wish to put a new drug product on the market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no conditional construction here. The phrase *would have to be interpreted* indicates that having to interpret the difference is an inevitable outcome of there being a difference in the first place. The phrase *should be investigated* indicates that there is some sort of moral obligation for this to happen. The sentences, therefore do not mean the same thing. Which one you will want to use will depend on what you are trying to say.

Notice that backshifted verb forms do not automatically indicate that something is unreal. Consider the following example:

- If he had measles he would have exactly those very symptoms that he is now displaying.

This can easily be said to persuade someone that that the patient does indeed have the measles. Notice that we *have* to use a so-called second conditional here. If we don't the sentence won't make sense:

- If he has the measles, he has exactly those symptoms that he has.

So although we often have to use so-called second conditionals when something is an imagined or unreal situation, this does not work the other way round. Because a situation is described in a second conditional it does not mean that the situation is unlikely to happen or that it won't happen. Quite often the reverse is true!

Comment: Thank you! So the sentences differ slightly in their "moral obligation/inevitable outcome" meaning but basically say the same thing: if there is a difference, it will be interpreted.

Comment: @CowperKettle Pretty much. They both imply that the difference will be interpreted, but the *should* version also allows for this not to happen in real life (in other words it represents the interpretation as an ideal outcome, but does not automatically confirm that this will actually happen).

Comment: Ah! So it's probably better to use **must**.

Comment: @CowperKettle Probably so!

Answer (score 3):

We are talking about a (future-looking) conditional necessity.

> Any observed significant difference ...

That is semantically equivalent to "If you happen to observe a significant difference, it {statement of conditional necessity}..."

> Yes, you could take the later train instead, but then you {should} | {must} | {would have to} run to make your connection.

**Should** doesn't convey the necessity

**Must** doesn't convey optimally that it is just a *conditional* necessity

**would have to**  conveys 'conditional necessity'